# Unable to accept android licenses while running flutter doctor

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Well when i am trying to accept android license on command prompt by typing "flutter doctor --android-licenses" this error appears everytime

" Exception in thread " main" java.Lang.NoclassDeffounderror:javax/xml/bind/annotation/xmlschema"

How do i solve this error

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your cmd (not from android studio terminal)
2. run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
3. press y to accept every license.

If it didn't work, try this command: (at the cmd too)

```
"android sdk path"\tools\bin\sdkmanager --licenses
```